# Use of Riesz Representation theorem here

Tags: functional-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

I'm working through Conways Functional analysis book right now, and I got a bit stumped, I just want to make sure I'm approaching the problem correctly. The problem statement goes as follows: Let $H = l^2(\mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}) $. Suppose $\{a_n\} \in H$. If $|\lambda| <1$ and $L: H \to \mathbb{F}$ is defined by $L( \{a_n\}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n\lambda^{n-1} $ find the vector $h_0$ in $H$ such that $L(h)= \langle{h},h_0\rangle$  for all $h$.

Just making sure all I really have to do here is show that $L$ is bounded and linear, and then use the Riesz theorem here? Its clear to me that this is linear, and showing that it is bounded shouldn't take too much work, my concern comes from finding the correct $h_0$. I was just looking for some guidance on this problem.

Comment: You just have to find $h_0$. The point of this is to find $h_0$ directly; Riesz theorem is not useful here.

Comment: Isn't this a direct application of Riesz theorem though? There's another problem very similar to this in Conways book (just without the n and with $\lambda$ to the $n$ instead of $n-1$ and I used Riesz theorem to figure out what $h_0$ would be.

Comment: On the surface, Riesz theorem only says that $h_0$ exists. For finding $h_0$ in a concrete situation, Riesz theorem alone isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but from what I gathered, its clearly linear so I won't bother showing that to be true. To show that it is bounded we have that $$| L(a_n)|^2 = \left\|\sum_{n=1}^\infty (na_n\lambda^{n-1})^2 \right\| \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|(na_n)^2\lambda^{2(n-1)}\|= \sum_{n=1}^\infty |na_n|^2|\lambda|^{2(n-1)} = \|a \|_2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|n^2\lambda^{2(n-1)}\|$$

I'd like to argue that this is bounded and will go to $0$ since $\lambda$ will to go $0$ faster than $n^2$ to infinity but I'm not sure if what I have now is enough to conclude that. If so, then $L$ is a bounded linear functional and by Riesz theorem we have that $L = \langle h,h_0 \rangle$. I would like to think that we can have $h_0 = \frac{\overline{\lambda^{n-1}}}{n}$ since this would be in $l^2$. Upon picking this $h_0$ we would obtain, with the geometric series that  $$\|h_0 \|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  |\lambda^{2(n-1)}| = \frac{1}{|1-\lambda^2|} \implies \|h_0\| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-|\lambda^2|}}$$

Comment: the series $\sum n^2 \lambda^{2(n-1)}$ is converging by root test.

Comment: also $h_{0,n} = n \bar\lambda^{n-1}$.

Comment: Okay, thats fine by me, I can make sense of that.